# Alternative to Map of java.lang.Object

Tags: java, design-patterns, architecture, software-design

So, I have to build a new Java application and I have a scenario where I'm inclined to use a Map of Objects with casts all around. I just don't like this idea though, but can't figure out a better solution.

Here's the scenario: I have some user input along with a tag that defines the action to be taken. First, based on the tag, the user input will be enriched with one or more objects, and then it will be passed along to a validator machine to be processed. These validators are somewhat generic, so they can be of use to one or more tags. That's where the Map comes in, it will be the validators input, because they know which key of the map to use.

I have been looking at the Chain of Command design pattern, but it uses a single request, and in my case the request can vary depending on the tag. Also, it's main purpose is already achieved with my validator machine.

Is there a better solution for this?

Comment: It is pretty hard to understand, what you want to achieve. Consider sketching and posting some code.

Comment: Read the book Effective Java buy Joshua Bloch. Specifically, Item 29: Consider typesafe heterogeneous containers. You'll find the book as PDF on the web, but you should buy a physical copy and read it end to end.

Comment: Thanks @SeanPatrickFloyd, this is pretty much close to what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to write your own typesafe heterogeneous container, consider Netty's [AttributeMap](https://netty.io/wiki/using-as-a-generic-library.html#wiki-h3-11), available in the [netty-common](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.netty/netty-common) library.